# vba vlookup with a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am working on Excel with a kind of city directory,

I have a separated huge list of city ids. I would like to set a vlookup in order to get cities name from their ids...

Example of my active sheet :

```
 Id    Name
 1     NY
 2     LA
```

Example of what I am looking for (I only have Id for the moment):

```
 Id        New column
 34001     Beijing
 2078      Berlin
 3459      ...
 143
```

I achieved to copy/paste a single value, but I would clearly need some help to get multiple values with a loop.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: You can't just use a formula?  If you really want a VBA solution, you should post your existing code.

Comment: You could use `VLOOKUP` without any VBA code to do that.

Comment: I didn't know that I could escape VBA !

Comment: This is a classic example what VLOOKUP() is for - `VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,[range_lookup])` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797422(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/) goes through not just the methods available to you, but also the performance implications of each of them. In your case I think the Match method would be the best.

You would obviously need a data set containing all the two letter codes of countries alongside the country name.

I most often use the match method and here is how i would do that in your scenario:

```
dim pos as variant
dim i as integer
dim ws as worksheet      ' worksheet where you want to add new column
dim refsheet as worksheet      ' sheet with country code and name


for i = 1 to 256       ' or whatever range you want to work with

'if a match is found, pos will be assigned the row number where the match was found.
on error resume next      
   pos = Match(ws.cells(i,2), refsheet.Range("A1:A100",0)
on error goto 0

if Not iserror(pos) then
    ws.cells(i,3) = refsheet.cells(2,pos)
else
    ' action if a match was not found
endif

next i
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice example, I managed your code with my needs and that works, thank you for the article also !

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't use a formula, create a loop in your data range and loop in your lookup range just like a vlookup formula.

An example in attachment so you can change as you need:

```
Sub RangeLoop()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
Dim LKRng, DTRng As Range
Set DTRng = ws.Range("D3:D8")
Set LKRng = ws.Range("G3:G6")
Dim DTcl, LKcl As Variant

For Each DTcl In DTRng
    For Each LKcl In LKRng
        If LKcl = DTcl Then
            LKcl.Offset(0, 1) = DTcl.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Next LKcl
Next DTcl

End Sub
```

```html
<img  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mdNd.png" height="243" width="569">
```

[Excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mdNd.png)